# Parameter error, SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, forms, parameters

So I'm getting SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined, when I try to submit my form.  I have a reservations folder with a index.php file that has an include file as reservations.html.php which has the forms in html.

So my forms in the reservations.html.php when filled out and has a value in first name will then try to post all the values in the form into the reservations table I have created in mysql.  Below are my code in the index.php

```
<?php

// Edit or Replace this try/catch statement to work with the current PHT configuration
include '../includes/db.inc.php';

// Modify the If statement so the try only runs if the First Name field has been submitted AND the honeypot field is empty ''
if (isset($_POST['myfname'])) {
    $myFName = $_POST['myfname'];
    $myTour = $_POST['tour'];
    $myLName = $_POST['mylname'];
    $myEmail = $_POST['myemail'];
    // If the if statement is true, save each form field value as a variable. These variable values will be used in the thank you page.

    // And run the try/catch to attempt to insert data in the database. Modify the INSERT statement to write all the form filed values (except the honeypot) to the database.
    try
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO reservations SET
          tour = :tour,
          fname = :fname,
          lname = :lname,
          email = :email';
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':tour', $myTour);
        $s->bindValue(':myfname', $myFName);
        $s->bindValue(':mylname', $myLName);
        $s->bindValue(':myemail', $myEmail);
        $s->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $error = 'Error adding submitted joke: ' . $e->getMessage();
        include '../includes/error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    // load the thank you page after the INSERT runs
    include 'success.html.php';
    // Add an else to load the initial page if the initial (line 19) if statement is false
} else {
    include 'reservations.html.php'; //Modify this to include the initial file for this folder
}
```

Comment: Your SQL syntax is suspect, but the cause of the error message is that you're defining `fname`, `lname` and `email`, but binding to `myfname`, `mylname` and `myemail`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for your insert statement is off, and appears to be hybrid between an insert and an update.  Try this version:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO reservations (tour, fname, lname, email) ";
$sql .= "VALUES (:tour, :fname, :lname, :email)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':tour', $myTour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':fname', $myFName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':lname', $myLName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $myEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

To be clear here, a SQL insert statement takes the following things:

- The `INSERT INTO` keywords, followed by a list of columns
- Then a VALUES clause, followed by a tuple containing the values to be inserted

There is also an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, which uses a select statement to provide the values, but you are not using this form.